# Unresolved imports in VSCode Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

While programming in VSCode, Python I imported a module named Selenium. However, VS Code is Showing me an error, saying unresolved import selenium. I had installed selenium yesterday only using the `pip`
command. Please do help me out

Comment: Did you select the correct interpreter for the project?

Comment: Yes, I have Python 3.9.1 64 bit version installed and the project interpreter is set to the same version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended that you use the command "`python --version`"(or `python3 --version`) in the VS Code terminal to check whether the python used in the terminal is the same as the one displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code, or use "`pip --version`"(or `pip3 --version`) to check the source of the module installation tool "pip", the module is installed at this location:

[image]

If the python results displayed are inconsistent, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter the python environment selected in the lower left corner of VS Code.

check: (`pip show selenium`)

[image]

Run:

[image]

In addition, please try to reload VS Code after installation to make it recognize this module.

Answer (score 0):

Select on the bottom left (status bar) the proper interpreter for your environment.

If you created a virtual environment, it will be shown with parentheses, as here:

[image]